# If $f:R\to R$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2-3$, find $f^{-1} (-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

If $f:R\to R$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2-3$, find $f^{-1} (-1)$

My Attempt :
 $$f(x)=x^2-3$$
$$y=x^2-3$$

Then how to proceed further?

Comment: set $y = -1$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: There is no inverse to $f$ on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is not a function.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales,  why is it so?

Comment: @Ramanujan To have an inverse, a function must be bijective (that means one to one) on its domain. Your function is not bijective. You can use a horizontal line test to see if a certain function has an inverse. Since a horizontal line cuts your function at more than one point, it does not have an inverse function. It does have an inverse *mapping* but it is not a function unless you restrict it to either positive or negative square roots.

Comment: If $f (-1)=x^2-3$ what is/are x?

Comment: @fleablood,  what do you mean?

Comment: John Wayland bales.  $f^{-1} $ doesn't always mean a function (which requires one distinct output value for for each input).  Often $f^{-1}(value) $ means the set of all x such that f (x)=value.  If f is 1-1 then it is a function, but if f isn't, it is not.

Comment: If $f (x)=x^2-3=-1$ what is/are x?

Comment: @fleablood In the context of algebra-precalculus $f^{-1}(-1)$ does does refer to a specific number, not to a pre-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 f\left( x \right) = x^{2} - 3
$$
The function has two $x$ values that map to $y = -1$.

[image: dashed]

---

$$
 \color{blue}{f^{-1}(y) = \sqrt{x+3}} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f^{-1}\left( -1 \right) = \sqrt{2}
$$
$$
 \color{red}{f^{-1}(y) = -\sqrt{x+3}}\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad f^{-1}\left(-1 \right) = -\sqrt{2}
$$

[image: pick a branch]

Comment: your answers don't match with the options given in book

Comment: @Ramanujan Without the benefits of having your book, one makes a best guess. In some classes instructors would ask students to specify a branch.

Comment: Your definition is incorrect, it should be $f^{-1} (y) $. Alternatively, replace $y$ with $x$ on the RHS.

Comment: @dantopa, some previous comments say that the function has no inverse?  What's your opinion on this?

Comment: The function has no inverse *function*.  All functions will have sets of inverse values (some empty) for specific output.

Comment: @Ramanujan The figures were included to help you decide what convention to use. If you are taught that the dashed line can't cross the function twice, then there is no inverse.

Comment: @dantopa,, the given function is not injective,  is it?

Comment: @amanujan: Not injective as seen in first picture.

Comment: @dantopa, then why /how does the inverse exist?

Comment: @ Ramanujan: Use that criterion to conclude there is no inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Without rigorous proof, we assume that the inverse of $f(x)$ exists, otherwise the problem would be meaningless. Let $g$ be the inverse of $f$. By definition then, $g(f(x)) = x \forall x \in D$ (D is the domain). We must find $g(-1)$ note that $f(2) = -1$. Thus $g(f(2))$ should give the required answer, which we find to be simply 2.

Hence answer is 2.

Comment: Btw, the problem is incorrect, as there cannot exist any inverse in R. Change it to R+ and there exists an answer, else forget whatever i said.